# MSSQL - Retrieving the top 5 time series within a query

Tags: sql-server, time-series-database

I'm utilizing the [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) site with MSSQL for my querying of time series and attempting to write 5 time series to a graph, my current query is

```sql
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(second, '1970-01-01', date)/1800)*1800 as time, 
       name as metric, 
       SUM(num/1.201) as value
FROM table
WHERE CAST(date AS DATE) BETWEEN '2020-05-27T19:13:49Z' 
                             AND '2020-05-29T19:13:49Z'
GROUP BY FLOOR(DATEDIFF(second, '1970-01-01', date)/1800)*1800, 
         name 
ORDER BY 1, 
         SUM(num) DESC
```

and this successfully returns multiple time series for my graph, but I have over 100 names/series and only want the top 5 series (by sum) to be displayed, any insight would be appreciated for ways of accomplishing this or just routes to explore as possibilities.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Move this query into CTE. Replace ordering with `ORDER BY SUM(num)` and add `TOP 5`. In outer query apply needed ordering.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)